# How to pass data from multiple activities to on activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 5 activities :
*Activity 1 ( details of one game tournament (
*Activity 2 (details of another game tournament) and so on....
*Activity 5 ( payment activity)

In each activity there is some data with one button and I want to send that data to payment activity whenever user clicks any activity(1-4)

Comment: Well.. what is the problem? If you can do it from nr 1 you can do it from nr 2 i would say.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent to send data between activities

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Another.class);
intent.putExtra(“message_key”, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

then use this code to get your data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getStringExtra(“message_key”);
```

Happy coding

Comment: Actually I want to send data from multiple activities....like if I want to send data from activity1 I don't to want to show data from others activity

Comment: Can you give me an example. People don't understand what you are asking for. That is why we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try SharedPreferences

creat object class

```
object Session {

    private val NAME = "SOME_NAME"
    private val MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    private lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences

    fun init(context: Context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(NAME, MODE)
    }

    private inline fun SharedPreferences.edit(operation: (SharedPreferences.Editor) -> Unit) {
        val editor = edit()
        operation(editor)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun setString(tag: String, value: String) {
        preferences.edit {
            it.putString(tag, value)
        }
    }

    fun getString(tag: String) = preferences.getString(tag, "")
}
```

init that in Application inside onCreate

```
class MyApp: Application(){
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Session.init(this)
    }
}
```